# tcsh reading columns of a text file into variables

Tags: global-variables, tcsh, file-read

I have a text file in the that looks like:

```
Jose Santiago:385-898-8357:385-555-5555:38 Fife Way, Abilene, TX 39673:1/5/58:95600

Tommy Savage:408-724-0140:408-777-0121:1222 Oxbow Court, Sunnyvale, CA 94087:5/19/66:34200

Yukio Takeshida:387-827-1095:387-888-1198:13 Uno Lane, Ashville, NC 23556:7/1/29:57000

Vinh Tranh:438-910-7449:438-999-0000:8235 Maple Street, Wilmington, VM 29085:9/23/63:68900
```

I am trying to write a tcsh script that will read the text file and assign each colon delimited field to a variable, with the exception of the name, which I want set to two separate variables.  I have tried several things, but can't get this to work.  I'm sorry, but I'm a novice.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the name variable will always have only two words separated by a space, you could first replace that space by a `:` and then use cut to get the field into variables:

```
sed 's/ /:/' <filename >new_file
set var1 = `cut -f1 -d ':' new_file`
set var2 = `cut -f2 -d ':' new_file`
set var3 = `cut -f3 -d ':' new_file`
```

etc... for each field in your file

PS: If you don't mind rewriting your original file, you can replace inline:

```
set -i.bak 's/ /:/' filename
```